# Discrete independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ implies $\mathbb{E}[f(X) \,\, g(Y)] = \mathbb{E} \left[ f(X) \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ g(Y) \right]$

Tags: solution-verification, random-variables, expected-value, independence

I'm trying to prove the following identity ($X: \Omega \rightarrow E \subseteq R$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow F \subseteq R$ are independent random variables, so $P(X \cap Y) = P(X) \, P(Y)$).

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X) \,\, g(Y)] = \mathbb{E} \left[ f(X) \right] \,\, \mathbb{E} \left[ g(Y) \right]
$$

Is my proof correct?
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[ f(X) \, g(Y)\big] &= \sum \limits _{\substack{x \in E \\ y \in F}} f(x) \, g(y) \, P(X \cap Y) =
&& \text{independence} \\
&= \sum \limits _{\substack{x \in E \\ y \in F}} f(x) \, g(y) \, P(x) \, P(y) = \\
&= \sum \limits _{\substack{x \in E \\ y \in F}} f(x) \, P(x) \, g(y) \, P(y) =
 \\
&= \left( \sum \limits _{x \in E} f(x) \, P(x) \right) \,
\left( \sum \limits _{y \in F} g(y) \, P(y) \right) =
 \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ f(X) \right] \, \mathbb{E} \left[ g(Y) \right]
\end{align}
$$

Comment: If $E$ and $F$ are infinite then do you mean that LHS exists iff RHS exists or not?

Comment: Hello @BotnakovN. I'm ignorant about that aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f=0$ and $Eg(Y)$ does not exist. Then LHS is not equal to RHS because LHS exists and RHS doesn't exist. So the proof doesn't work.

But if you suppose that $Ef(X)$ and $Eg(Y)$ exist then your proof is correct, but it may be useful to prove that operations with sums are correct under these conditions. Because the example above shows, that such operations are not always correct.